# How to save the data from one table to another table when button is clicked in yii2?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, yii2

I have 3 table (in database phpmyadmin) which are: `appointment`, `approveAppointment` and `rejectAppointment`. All of the column names inside each table is the same.

I'm currently develop an appointment management system between student and lecturer where when student book for appointment in (frontend/view/appointment/create) all the data will be insert in appointment table in db.

Lecturer will get all the data of the appointment make by student to them the data will retrieve from table 'appointment' and shown in (frontend/view/appointment-confirmation/index using crud as in figure 1) and the lecturer need to view and will make a confirmation either approve or reject by clicking the button (shown in figure 2)

when lecturer click button approve, i want all the data about the appointment insert to table 'approveAppointment'. if the lecturer click button reject, all the data insert to table 'rejectAppointment'.

figure 1[image]

figure 2 [image]

so this is my code for appointment-confirmation controller (actionApprove) :

```
 public function actionApprove($id)
{
    $model = new ApproveAppointment();
    $model->save();
}
```

this is code for approveAppointment controller

```
public function actionApproveAppointment()
{
    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost && Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
    $appointment_id = Yii::$app->request->post('appID');
    $appointmentModel = $this->findAppointmentModel($appointment_id);

    //model instance for the approve model
    $model = new ApproveAppointment();
    $model->attributes=$appointmentModel->attributes;

    //set the response format
    Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\base\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

    $response['success'] = false;

    try {
        $model->approveAppointment();
        $response['success'] = true;
        $response['message'] = "Appointment is approved";
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $response;
}
```

this is code for my view

```
$appID = $model->appID;
$js = <<<JS
$("#approve").on('click',function(){
    let data=[];
    data.push({name:"appID",value:$appID});
    data.push({name:yii.getCsrfParam(),value:yii.getCsrfToken()});
    $.ajax({
        url: "index.php?r=appointment-confirmation/approveAppointment",
        data:data,
        type:'POST',
        dataType:'json',

    }).done(function( data ) {
          //display an alert or insert inside the html div for showing        

    messages
         alert(data.message);
    });
});

  JS;
  $this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

and the approve button inside my view

```
<?= Html::a('Approve', ['approve', 'id'=>"approve"], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

Comment: Are we talking about mysql tables?

Comment: i've update the question. sorry its a bit lengthy but i really need help.

Comment: do mark the answer as correct if it worked for you

Answer (score 1):

WHY YOU NEED 3 similar TABLES? you can make "status" column in appointment table  and give value "approved","rejected","review"!

Comment: because it is used by diff users and each of them have diff access to the data. i need to call the data in different view/interfaces (eg: approve appointment in upcoming appointment and reject appointment in rejected appointment view)

Answer (score 0):

You havent added the code for the Approve button and Reject Buttons neither you have added the model name so i will assume that you have the following model names change them accordingly

- `Appointment`.
- `ApproveAppointment`.
- `RejectAppointment`.

Now about the requirements all you have to do is use the following general way

```
$copyToModel->attributes=$copyFromModel->attributes
```

This will automatically copy all the values from one model to another then you can save them by calling the `save()` method. i will add the code for `actionApproveAppointment` only.

You can use `$.ajax()` or `$.post()` to submit the id of the appointment to the action add below to the top of your view file i am assuming you have the `app_id` column in the model that you are using in the appointment view page that you have shown inside the image. Just add an `id="approve"` to your button Approve in the html.

```
$app_id = $model->app_id;
$js = <<<JS
    $("#approve").on('click',function(){
        let data=[];
        data.push({name:"app_id",value:$app_id});
        data.push({name:yii.getCsrfParam(),value:yii.getCsrfToken()});
        $.ajax({
            url: "index.php?r=appointment-confirmation/approve-appointment",
            data:data,
            type:'POST',
            dataType:'json',

        }).done(function( data ) {
              //display an alert or insert inside the html div for showing messages
             alert(data.message);
        });
    });

JS;
$this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

Add the below inside your `ApproveAppointmentController`

```
public function actionApproveAppointment()
{
    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost && Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        $appointment_id = Yii::$app->request->post('app_id');
        $appointmentModel = $this->findAppointmentModel($appointment_id);

        //model instance for the approve model
        $model = new ApproveAppointment();
        $model->attributes=$appointmentModel->attributes;

        //set the response format
        Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\base\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        $response['success'] = false;

        try {
            $model->approveAppointment();
            $response['success'] = true;
            $response['message'] = "Appointment is approved";
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $response;
    }
}

protected function findAppointmentModel( $id ) {
    if ( ($model = Appointment::findOne ( $id )) !== null ) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException ( 'The requested page does not exist.' );
    }
}
```

Add the below inside your `ApproveAppointment` model

```
public function approveAppointment(){
    if(!$this->save()){
        throw new \Exception(implode("<br />", ArrayHelper::getColumn($this->errors, 0)));
    }
}
```

Comment: thankyou for your answer. but i didnt managed to get what i want using your code. i've update the question incase you can help me again :) i really need your help

Comment: @beginnerQueen , **but i didnt managed to get what i want using your code.** isnt helping much also the code you have added i cant see any updates that i provided in my answer, i can help you solve the problem but not write the whole code. you must integrate the changes that i have provided and then come back if something is not working

Comment: okay where should i put this : $copyToModel->attributes=$copyFromModel->attributes? when using your code i get this error : syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) at this code $model->attributes=appointmentModel->attributes;

Comment: @beginnerQueen you dont need to put `$copyToModel->attributes= $copyFromModel->attributes` anywhere that line is for general understanding, and the error you are getting is because i missed a `$` beforre `appointmentModel->attributes` i have updated the answer please copy the `actionApproveAppointment` again

Comment: sir, i'd used your code but the data not save in the database. i have update my code like how you gave me.

Comment: there is no error but the the table approve appointment in db is empty thats means the data is not insert in the db